# Is there a way to print or call on a void methods parameter in java

Tags: java, arrays, methods, parameters, arguments

I've been teaching myself java out of a book and I am trying to find out if I have a void method and I pass in two empty arrays through its parameter list, how can I use the methods parameters for later use. So for instance I put in 3 names with there score in like this "    John Doe 98.3 " don't mind the parentheses. I want to make a sorting method later and be able to call that to sort the arrays String[] score, String[] names in the parameter list. In main after I call the method I try to print the array that I used for the parameter (on line 26 for me) but it returns null. How do I get the parameter list data from this void method?

Would prefer not to use objects unless there is no other way. Thanks for the insight.

```
 // imports

 import java.util.Scanner;

 import java.util.regex.Matcher;

 import java.util.regex.Pattern;



 public class Example {

     public static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
     public static void main(String[] args) {
    

    int n;

    n = numOfStudents();

    input.nextLine();

    String[] studentScore;
    studentScore = new String[n];

    String[] studentNames;
    studentNames = new String[n];

    studentInfo(n, studentScore, studentNames);
    
    // prints null
    System.out.println(studentNames[1]);


 }

public static int numOfStudents(){

    int students = 0;
    System.out.print("Enter the number of students: ");
    students = input.nextInt();

    while (students < 1) {
        System.out.print("Number of students must be greater than 0: ");
        students = input.nextInt();
    }
    return students;
}

public static void studentInfo(int num, String[] score, String[] names){


    String[] arr;
    arr = new String[num];

    score = new String[num];

    names = new String[num];

    String strPattern = "-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?";

    for(int i = 0; i < num; i++) {


        System.out.print("Enter a name and test score: ");
        arr[i] =input.nextLine();

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(strPattern);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(arr[i]);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            score[i] = matcher.group();
        }

        names[i] = arr[i].replaceAll(strPattern, "");

    }
    System.out.println(score[1] + names[1]);
}
```

}

Comment: You probably don't want `score = new String[num]; names = new String[num];` in the body of the method.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to know the difference between a *reference* and an *object*.

In java, **all** variables can only hold a small, fixed size amount of data, no exceptions. So, how in the blazes does `Person p = new Person();` work, you should be wondering - you can make your own Person class and stuff it to the gills with fields with no issue; clearly a Person object can easily be neither small nor fixed size.

References is the answer.

This is what happens:

- An object is created by invoking the Person constructor.
- The *reference* to this object is the value of this invocation.
- Your `p` variable holds this *reference*. This is a pointer; it lets java know where to find the object. **It is not the object itself**.

Imagine a giant beach. Objects are buried treasure. Variables are treasure maps written on little wipeable handheld whiteboards.

```
Person p = new Person();
```

is thus equivalent to:

- Create a new treasure chest.
- Bury it.
- Draw the location to it on a map.
- Return the map.

Next important thing to keep in mind: Java is **pass by value**. In java, those little whiteboards are **never** passed. Whatever whiteboards you hold are yours and yours alone. You cannot give them away nor receive any. Instead, whenever you want to give data to a method, you can instead show them what to copy on *their* whiteboards, and similarly, when a method returns information to you, all you get to is copy what is on their whiteboard.

Final important realization: Primitives (long, int, short, byte, double, float, boolean, and char - the list is hardcoded, you can't make your own) are all small and fixed size and just fit on these little whiteboards.

This explanation isn't 'java is a lot like this'. Nono, java is **exactly** like this. This metaphor does not have any failure modes; it is a pirate, beaches, and whiteboards version of how java works.

Note that `=` is assignment: In our pirate world it is the equivalent of wiping out a little whiteboard and copying something else on it. In contrast to `foo.bar`, `foo[x]`, `synchronized (foo)`, `switch (foo)` - these all **dereference**, meaning: In our pirate world those all involve: "Follow the map and dig in the sand".

Putting it all together, it explains the behaviour you witness. Let's go line by line through your code:

- `String[] studentScore;`

Conjure out of thin air a new whiteboard. We shall name it `studentScore`, and we restrict it: It may either be blank, or have a map that leads to treasure of the `String[]` type; it is completely impossible to make maps to any other kind of treasure with it, the universe (the JVM) won't let it happen.

- `studentScore = new String[n];`

This does multiple separate things. First, it conjures up a new treasure chest. It contains just enough room for n treasure maps (it's more like a little file folder than a big chest). After all, Strings themselves are objects too - they are treasures, and all string variables and references are therefore maps, not the whole thing. An array that can hold 'n' strings really just holds n treasure maps to strings. Next, this says: Draw on your `studentScore` whiteboard a map to this newly conjured up treasure file folder. Like all arrays of non-primitive types, it starts out with n blank maps. (a blank map = a `null` value).

- `studentInfo(n, studentScore, studentNames);`

Your whiteboards are yours and cannot be handed out. So, this means: Walk over to Misses `studentInfo`. studentInfo knows how many arguments it has (in java all methods always have a set number of arguments), so she's ready to do your bidding, holding 3 fresh new blank whiteboards. You show her 3 whiteboards of your own: One with `n` written on it directly (`n` is an `int`, a primitive, therefore it's just written on your board. There's no map and no treasure involved), one with a treasure map leading to your `studentScore` buried treasure, and one to another buried treasure chest. Misses `studentInfo` duly copies these values and maps over on her 3 boards and goes to work.

- `score = new String[num];`

Misses `studentInfo` takes her treasure map to the treasure you made and buried and **wipes it clean**, then, she conjures up an entirely new treasure chest, buries it, and copies the location over on her whiteboard.

- `score[i] = matcher.group();`

Misses `studentInfo` fetches a shovel, follows her `score` treasuremap, digs down, and opens the treasure, which is a file folder with room for a bunch of treasure maps written on little whiteboards. She finds the `i`-th whiteboard, takes it out, wipes out whatever is there, and copies the treasuremap over that Mr `matcher` is currently showing her, as a result of doing his thing.

- ... method ends ....

Misses `studentInfo` is done, and she returns nothing, so **she takes her whiteboards and tosses them in the garbage**.

- You are standing there, your whiteboards are of course still completely unmodified, maps to treasure that nobody touched - maps to treasures that still hold all blank maps. You fetch a shovel, follow your map, dig down, open the file folder, and pull out the first little whiteboard. Of course it is blank.

### So how do you 'fix' this?

Don't use `=` in your `studentInfo` method. Alternatively, do that, but `return` that value (you can only return one thing, so if your method needs to modify 2 treasure chests, that 'return it' plan is not going to work out).

Just ditch the `score = new String[num];` part. If you do *not* do that, then your line of `score[i] = foo` digs down to find the treasure that **the map misses `studentInfo` copied over from your little whiteboard** leads to. And then she modifies what she finds there - which is great, because when *you* follow *your* map, it's a different map, but goes to the same place, so when *you* dig down, you'll see the effects of what Misses `studentInfo` did.